# Array push only works inside the callback

Tags: arrays, node.js, count, array-push

I'm trying to update an array with some mongoose values. But it only works if the array.push is inside the callback function. I've tried to code in several ways but outside the callback I always get an empty array. Here are some code:

```
let y = [];

Shops.countDocuments({ dt_encerramento: { $gte: jan, $lte: abr }})
   .then(function(os) {
     y.push(os);
   })
   .catch(err => { throw err; });

 console.log(y);
```

Using async/await:

```
let y = [];

async function docs() {
   const numDocs = await Shops.countDocuments({ dt_encerramento: { $gte: jan, $lte: abr }}).exec();
   return numDocs;
}

docs().then(function (err,n) { y.push(n); });

console.log(y);
```

Help, please. I don't know what to do...

Comment: Why in the first function you do not use the `exec()` method and the second one you used it?

Comment: Put the console.log() inside the callback function, on the line after you modify the array. Because it's async, the array has not yet been modified at the time you log it.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I just forgot the exec(), but it doesn't alter the results.

Comment: @Martin, thanks for your reply. Your suggestion works but I need the updated array outside the callback, how could I retrieve it?

Comment: @FábioMedeiros I would recommend you read up on the basic concepts of Asynchronous code. Basically you cannot assume the code executes in the order it is written so even though your console.log(y) is on the last line, it does not mean the  push() has happened yet. I can recommend MDN as a source of learning https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are missing a promise.

```
let y = [];

const docs = async () => {
   return await Promise.all(Shops.countDocuments({ dt_encerramento: { $gte: jan, $lte: abr }}).exec());
}

const docsToPush = docs()
y.push(docsToPush)
console.log(y);
```

Comment: @FábioMedeiros Just an extra note, I'm making the assumption you are using this to build a web app or api of some sort, you could change the const to var but I would recommend against this, using var opens you up to possible security threats.